# How to create conditional dropdown list using Microsoft access db?

Tags: database, ms-access-2010

I need your help in this please.
I want to have a conditional dropdown list in access database, this is an example;

Table1

Column1 | Column2 | Column3
1       | dropdown list with two option “ fruit or vegetable”

If user select fruit I want to see all fruits option in column3 as a dropdown list also. And verses varsa.

How can i do this?
I’m waiting for your answers! :)

Comment: No answers until now:(, is it impossible?

Comment: I guess it is. But probably no one understands what _vice versa_ means in this context.